# JVM Default Arguments

Tags: java, jvm

I can't believe I couldn't find this on the web, I must have been using some bad search terms...

Anyway, is there any way to set some default arguments for the JVM. I'm running JRE 1.8.0_73 if it makes much difference.

The goal I am trying to achieve is attaching an agent to every instance of the JVM that starts, in this particular case an applet. I know I could start the applet from the command line and specify the arguments there but I would like to know if there is a way to globally set some command line arguments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a system environment variable named **_JAVA_OPTIONS** and set its value to all the default arguments you need to pass to the JVM.